# Why ng-model in AngularJs doesn't select value?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this array in angular:

```
$scope.skins = [
    { code : "default", name : "DEFAULT_TXT" },
    { code : "aero", name : "AERO_TXT" },
    { code : "navy", name : "NAVY_TXT" },
    { code : "facebook", name : "FACEBOOK_TXT" },
    { code : "turquoise", name : "TURQUOISE_TXT" },
    { code : "lime", name : "LIME_TXT" },
    { code : "green", name : "GREEN_TXT" },
    { code : "purple", name : "PURPLE_TXT" },
    { code : "white", name : "WHITE_TXT" },
    { code : "concrete", name : "CONCRETE_TXT" },
    { code : "watermelon", name : "WATERMELON_TXT" },
    { code : "lemonade", name : "LEMONADE_TXT" }
]
```

And I have created a select options with ng-options. I have set the ng-model by some value, but it doesn't select it. What I do wrong?

Here is the full example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/wk4zupuj/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you ng-model binds to the object in the list, not the 'code' property, try this javascript code instead.

```
app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var defSkin = { code: "white", name: "WHITE_TXT" };
    $scope.skins = [
        { code: "default", name: "DEFAULT_TXT" },
        { code: "aero", name: "AERO_TXT" },
        { code: "navy", name: "NAVY_TXT" },
        { code: "facebook", name: "FACEBOOK_TXT" },
        { code: "turquoise", name: "TURQUOISE_TXT" },
        { code: "lime", name: "LIME_TXT" },
        { code: "green", name: "GREEN_TXT" },
        { code: "purple", name: "PURPLE_TXT" },
        defSkin,
        { code: "concrete", name: "CONCRETE_TXT" },
        { code: "watermelon", name: "WATERMELON_TXT" },
        { code: "lemonade", name: "LEMONADE_TXT" }
    ]

    $scope.opts = [];
    $scope.opts.sidebarSkin = defSkin;

});
```

Comment: It worked. but there is no need to enter the `defSkin` inside the array. You could leave it as it was and it still work.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this

```
$scope.opts = {};
```

and remove `track by` ...

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/p1ck5vzd/)

Comment: I need the track by

Answer (score 1):

$scope.opts is an object not an array,

```
$scope.opts = {};
```

**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/wk4zupuj/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-selected** to select particular value.[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wk4zupuj/7/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <select class="form-control" ng-model="opts.sidebarSkin" name="sidebarTemplate" ng-options="skin.code as skin.name  for skin in skins" ng-selected="code == opts.sidebarSkin">

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Angular Js Code

```
app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.skins = [
        { code : "default", name : "DEFAULT_TXT" },
        { code : "aero", name : "AERO_TXT" },
        { code : "navy", name : "NAVY_TXT" },
        { code : "facebook", name : "FACEBOOK_TXT" },
        { code : "turquoise", name : "TURQUOISE_TXT" },
        { code : "lime", name : "LIME_TXT" },
        { code : "green", name : "GREEN_TXT" },
        { code : "purple", name : "PURPLE_TXT" },
        { code : "white", name : "WHITE_TXT" },
        { code : "concrete", name : "CONCRETE_TXT" },
        { code : "watermelon", name : "WATERMELON_TXT" },
        { code : "lemonade", name : "LEMONADE_TXT" }
      ]

      $scope.opts = {};
      $scope.opts.sidebarSkin = "white";

    });
```